# Convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

So, in my complex analysis notes my prof typed the following

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z - z_0} = \frac{-1}{1 - \frac{z}{z_0}} = \frac{-1}{z_0}\sum_{n = 0}^{ \infty} (\frac{z}{z_0})^n$$

How did we figure out that step why do we know that will have that following power series representation can someone explain that step ?

Comment: $z$ should be inside (not even on) the unit circle around $z_0$ for this to make sense. To see that in this case it works think in terms of absolute convergence.

Comment: The numerator in the middle term should not be $-1$. It should be $-1/z_0$. If that is what the  prof wrote, then it's a typo of his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the standard fact
$$
\sum_{n=0}^Nz^n=\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z},\qquad z\neq1. \tag1
$$ If $|z|<1$, then letting $N \to \infty$ in $(1)$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\frac{1}{1-z},\qquad |z|<1. \tag2
$$ Applying $(2)$ with $z \to\dfrac{z}{z_0}$ gives what your prof wrote, since
$$
\frac{1}{z-z_0}=-\frac{1}{z_0}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{z_0}}.
$$

Comment: I see I know this is true in the real case I didn't know it is also true for complex numbers.

Comment: why is this true for complex numbers as well can you explain ?

Comment: This is true also for complex numbers: we have used the same mathematical operations, valid in the complex field. Thanks!

Comment: alright thank you I understand...

Comment: Hi could you help me with the following problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555577/analytic-function-on-a-certain-domain