# Is this function being analytic on this domain

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

$f(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty e^{inz} e^{-n}/2i - e^{-inz} e^{-n}/2i$ I need to show that this function is analytic on the domain $\Sigma = \{z \in C \mid -1 < \operatorname{Im}(z) < 1\}$, to show this I need to consider some closed disc of radius $r > 0$ and show that it will converge uniformly by Weierstrass $M$-test but I don't have idea how to bound it.

Comment: I don't understand your notation in the exponents in the summation.

Comment: I have edited it  please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may recall that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n=\frac{1}{1-r},\qquad |r|<1. \tag1
$$ Applying $(1)$ with $r=e^{-(1-iz)}$ and with $r=e^{-(1+iz)}$  gives 
$$
\frac1{2i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-n(1-iz)}-\frac1{2i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-n(1+iz)}=\frac1{2i}\frac{1}{1-e^{-(1-iz)}}-\frac1{2i}\frac{1}{1-e^{-(1+iz)}}
$$ **provided that**
$$
\left|e^{-(1-iz)}\right|=e^{-1-\Im z}<1
$$ **and** $$
\left|e^{-(1+iz)}\right|=e^{-1+\Im z}<1
$$ that is

> $$
> -1<\Im z<1
> $$

as announced. The function is thus analytic on its domain.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be any compact subset of the domain $\Sigma $. There exists $r\in (0,1)$ such that $\forall z\in C (|\Im (z)|<r).$ For $|\Im (z)|<r$ the modulus of $\exp (i n z\pm n)$ is bounded above by $\exp (-n(1-|r|)).$ So for $z\in C$  the  modulus of the $n$th  term of the summation is bounded above by the $n$th term of  the converging geometric series $\sum_n \exp (-n(1-|r|)).$ Therefore the summation converges uniformly  on $C$.